# Reading Contact Notes field from Exchange

Tags: c#, exchange-server-2010

We are building an integration we Exchange 2010.

When we look at a contact through Outlook, there is a "Notes" field below the picture of the person, this contains update information.

We are able to find the data in the other fields but not this one. Anyone know what the field is called or where the data is stored.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is stored in a field called `ContactSchema.Body` which is not recognized as one of Contacts FirstClassProperties.

To include the Body property when loading a contact, you need to specify it.

```
Contact c = Contact.Bind(service, 
                         new ItemId(id), 
                         new PropertySet(BasePropertySet.FirstClassProperties,
                                         ContactSchema.Body ));
```

And you can now access `c.Body` without throwing an exception.